# Receiving POST data from Swift/iOS client request in ASP.net

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, swift

I'm currently coding a Swift app and I want to send a request containing a JSON string to my .NET backend/web service. However, when using this code in:

ASP.NET:

```
String jsonString = Request.Form["jsonString"];
```

Swift:

```
 let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.backend.com/backend.aspx")!;
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    request.HTTPBody = ("jsonString=" + jsonString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(dataString)

    }

    task.resume()    }
```

The string on my asp.net backend turns out to be null. For whatever reason, I can't seem to get the string to be retrieved from the request. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: the `guard let _:NSData` part is horrible. It unwraps and discards the unwrapped value, and then uses print("error") instead of printing the actual error. Later you have to unwrap the data, again... Bad, bad, and bad. Please give me the URL of the tutorial / site it comes from so that I can tell people not to use it... :p

Comment: @EricD I found it here: http://www.kaleidosblog.com/nsurlsession-in-swift-get-and-post-data

Do you know how I can fix my problem though? Can't seem to figure out why my request is empty in ASP

Comment: Thank you very much. // You say you get null on the ASP side, but what's happening on the Swift side? Is the String posted? Is there an error?

Comment: There isn't any error on the swift side and the string definitely has a value on the swift side. How do i test if the string gets posted?

Comment: Inspect `response`, but if `print(dataString)` works, then the String has been posted.

Comment: Yup print data string does work and I see the response in the console but I still can't get the string through response.form

Answer (score 0):

I used Alamofire module to handle the POST request.

```
        Alamofire.request(.POST, "someWebSite/api/someApi", parameters: ["Name":"Pancakes", "Price":9.99])
        .responseJSON{response in
            print("1", response.request)  // original URL request
            print("2", response.response) // URL response
            print("3", response.data)     // server data
            print("4", response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }
```